# Where does Apk file goes after 'build and run'?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So in the File->Build Settings I configurated my project, clicked **Build And Run**, it created an **apk file on my PC** and **ran it on my phone**. But does this apk is **saved** somewhere on my phone after I close my project? If so, then where?

I simply don't want to clog my phone with dozens of apks.

Comment: As long as the project name etc in the publishing settings stay the same your phone should anyway overwrite the existing app everytime. Afaik the APK isn't saved on the phone at all but only the app installed so you can simply uninstall it if not longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does get saved on the phone, just as it would if you downloaded an app from the Play Store, you need to manually uninstall all the apps you tested on your phone as they will take up room on your phone. Good thing is that new versions get older versions uninstalled automatically when you build and run, as long as the bundle identifier matches the one previously used

Comment: Thanks! Is there are any instructions on where to find those apks?

Comment: they go to the same location your other apps go, research into android app location, depending on the device this could be internal memory or sd card. anyways, its better to uninstall an ap using adb and pm (package manager?) based on bundle id than removing any files manually (you might get leftovers that you will never remove)